# Upload 'tsv' file to Google Colab / Jupyter Notebook

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, numpy, jupyter, colab

TSV(Tab separated Value) extension file can't be uploaded to google colab using pandas

Used this to upload my file

```
import io
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['Filename.csv']))

import io
stk = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['train.tsv']))
```

What i want is a tsv file should be uploaded and read into the dataframe **stk**

Answer (score 2):

You first need to upload your file. The io.BytesIO only reads from the uploaded. So first run:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

and select the file you would like to upload.

Also, when you load it into your pandas, you need the sep='\t':

```
tsk = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['train.tsv']), sep='\t')
```